# getting gridview's row's data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview which generate a link based on certain condition inside the Grid from code behind. What I want to achieve is when I click on that link, I want to catch all the information from the row that the link is in. So for example, if row 1, 2, and 4 has links in cell 5, When I click row 1's link, I want to get all the cell value from row 1. When I click on row 2's link, I want to get all the cell value from row 2, etc. I am somewhat close but not quite. When I click on row 2, I still get the same value from row 1, same as when I click on row 4, I get the same value from row 1. Can anyone help? In short, I want to get the row's value based on the link that's in the row. Here's my code:

```
$('a.SendEmail').click(function(e){
   var Name = $('#<%=GridView2.ClientID%> td:eq(1)').text();
   var Id = $('#<%=GridView2.ClientID%> td:eq(2)').text();
   var DeptName = $('#<%=GridView2.ClientID%> td:eq(3)').text();
   var Total = $('#<%=GridView2.ClientID%> td:eq(4)').text();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is more like this:

```
$("a.SendEmail").click(function(e) {
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");

    var name= row.children("td:eq(1)").text();
    .
    .
});
```

Bubble up to the row and then find the children.

HTH.

Comment: @Brian -- I've tried what you suggested, put an alert but when the alert comes back, I get an empty alert. My page has a master page so I dont know if "$(this)" will work.

Comment: this should refer to the hyperlink, so yes it should work.  My syntax could be a little off, but the idea is that at the hyperlink, you find the parent table row that the link is in, and then drill down to the children.  Another alternative: give the column a css class name, and use this approach: var name= row.find(".NameColumn:first").text();

Comment: Also, where do you have the alert and on what, on the row result set?

Comment: i have the alert set after setting the variable name.

Comment: If I use this, I get result of the first row ... var row = $(this).parents('tr:first'); var name= row.children('#<%=GridView2.ClientID%> td:eq(0)').text(); ... but when i click on another row, I get the same result.

Comment: You can never hard-code the GridView ID.  It will never work.  You have to access the children from the row.  The issue may not be then with accessing the row, try another alert, after getting the row variable: alert(row.length);  It should be one.

Comment: thanks Brian for your suggestion and help. it helped me a lot and I was able to resolve it.